# Can't start gvim from command line

Tags: gui, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gvim

I've been trying to get gvim to work on Ubuntu 20.04 with no luck. Initially I had issues with libQt5Core but finally resolved that by adding the path to the lib to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
Now I'm getting this error:

```
 gvim
Warning: Missing charsets in String to FontSet conversion
E665: Cannot start GUI, no valid font found
```

I'm at a total loss, can anyone make any suggestions where I go from here?

Comment: At this point it's not Gvim that's interesting. Gvim installed and ran on first attempt on my stock Ubuntu 20.04 (`sudo apt install vim vim-doc vim-gui-common`). So rather, tell us more about your system. Which Ubuntu flavor? (Are you on Lubuntu?) Which version? If you are on Lubuntu, see this: https://superuser.com/questions/446326/gvim-on-lubuntu

Comment: This information does definitely belong into your question text body. You should edit your question and include it. Also there is a tag for that: `windows-subsystem-for-linux`

Comment: windows-subsystem-for-linux doesn't work, but lsb_release -1 gives me No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

Comment: @Levente   Also in the .vimrc file is set guifont=Courier\ New\ 11. It appears that this font may not be available fc-list | grep Courier gives me:                                    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/c0419bt_.pfb: Courier 10 Pitch:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/c0611bt_.pfb: Courier 10 Pitch:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/c0582bt_.pfb: Courier 10 Pitch:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/c0583bt_.pfb: Courier 10 Pitch:style=Bold                           If this is the case I'll need to add more fonts?? of change the .vimrc??

Comment: To begin with, why is the plain, command-line-based original `vim` not sufficient to use in the WSL environment? Why pushing for the extra step of putting a graphical wrapper around vim that already works? (Also, I hardly have personal experience with WSL, so I won't be able to give you hints about what to tweak there.) My knowledge ends at suggesting using the `vim` command instead of `gvim`.

Comment: @Levente, OK one at a time, first I'm trying to get gvim because I prefer a gui editor for a lot of reasons that don't really matter, let's just say it's my preference and also because it's a challenge for me, I've been away from Linux, well actually for me Unix for a long time.Next, yes the .gvimrc does get called I've tested that, I tried adding the set guifont you mentioned but it also errors out. I guess from here I just need to find a font that will work and I should be good to go

Comment: if you want a decent gui don't use WSL2. use virtualization.

Comment: Are we sure that WSL is being used here? Someone other than the original poster edited the question to *add* that tag, but the OP doesn't seem to know what WSL is, considering it sounds like they tried to run `Windows-subsystem-for-Linux` as a *command*

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've at least found a temporary solution to this, I'll need to find a more permanent one at some point. But for now I've at least isolated it to a font issue.
I created a .gimvrc and for now only added one line: set guifont-*

Comment: Running into to many problems with WSL so I just replaced windows on one of my laptops with Ubuntu and made my newest a dual boot for now. All is well with a full install, no more lib problems,gvim works as expected. I don't plan on being in windows very often anyway.

Comment: `set guifont=*`, actually and in WSL2 it seems to use terminal font.  Not sure how to change.